# Answer on "Why do we have same chord but different name?"

Tags: discussion

[Why do we have same chord but different name?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/70191/why-do-we-have-same-chord-but-different-name/70235#70235)

I flagged this answer with the "not an answer" flag. Flag was declined because  *flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer*

IMO this makes no sense. My flag did not address the question of accuracy.  I flagged this answer because it does not answer the question "Why do we have same chord but different name?", and this answer does not address that point at all.

A while back I was scolded for using a wrong flag. Now I used the right flag, and it was declined for a reason not at all relevant to the flag...

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me as if the answer correctly asserts that the chords in question are not the same chords while incorrectly interpreting what the chords are. It's a mess, to be sure, but I think it's an honest *attempt* to answer the question and therefore the flag response makes sense to me.

A good example of "Not an answer" would be something like, *Yeah, I always wondered that also* or something that doesn't even try to be an answer to the question. Anything that would normally be a legitimate comment is an obvious case for a "Not an answer" flag.

---

Let me explain what I believe the "Not an answer" flag is for with an example.

Suppose the question is:

> **Q:** On a clear, sunlit day, on Earth, what color is the sky?

Clearly this is an answer:

> **A:** Blue

For the purposes of the flag (if I'm not mistaken), **this also is an answer, even though it is wrong**:

> **A:** Yellow

And for the purposes of the flag, **this is not an answer and should be flagged**:

> **A:** That reminds me of the time that I was looking at the sky and I remembered that corn flakes are the best cereal and have you noticed that clouds sometimes have funny shapes.

The "Yellow" answer is an *attempt* to answer the question, even though it is incorrect. I'm pretty sure that the "Not an answer" flag is not meant to be used on answers that attempt to answer but fail.

Again, this is just my attempt to explain why your flag was declined.

Comment: 1) This does not answer the question at all. The question was about an incorrect flag. That matter is not addressed here. 2) There are two ways to approach the original question: One is in @DavidBowling's answer : **Cdim7 and Cm7♭5 are not the same chord.** . The other is to explain that the same chord can have more than one name.  The answer in question does neither. It it means to day **they are not the same chord**, then **_say it_** - David Bowling had no problem doing so.

Comment: Five other meta users agree that this answer is an explanation for why your flag was declined. Perhaps you might carefully consider the second paragraph of my answer above. "Not an answer" is more for specific things, not for anything that doesn't fit the other flag categories. The specific things "Not an answer" is for are things that are comments or other questions. **Bad** answers or attempts to answer that fail to answer the question are not what the "Not an answer" flag is for. This is not the place to discuss how to answer the original question.

Comment: Why are you citing votes? Why not stick to facts, which are as follows: _not an answer_ : **This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question.** People vote on these forums for many reasons. Quite often "the early bird catches the worm" and you're the only answer. In plain English, Is there anywhere where that the answer in question attempts to answer the question? No, there is not.

Comment: I had no intention of flagging for poor quality - that's why I used the  "not an answer" flag! If the mod thinks it **is an answer** that is the correct response to give: **We think it is answer** - not twist my flag into something that it isn't. That is my question - the reason for the flag being declined was inappropriate. How have you answered that question? You have not. A triple whammy: An answer to a question on the main forum that doesn't answer the question; an answer on meta that doesn't answer the meta question, but instead explains that the original non-answer really is an answer.

Comment: This is making me dizzy  - not worth it. Good night.

Comment: @Stinkfoot Yeah, I guess I don't really worry about flags that much so I can't relate. Sorry you're upset. I think the assumption is that there's leeway in all things, including explanations for declining of flags. Whoever declined the flag wrote something that has the gist of why they declined it, but it's a rare thing that what some rights is exactly what you want to read. Everyone gets flags declined, often for reasons that don't make sense. It's just part of SE.

Comment: _Upset_ is not the correct word. _Annoyed_ is the term. I don't concern myself much with flags either, but this response was ludicrous, which is why I called attention to it.

Comment: @Stinkfoot "*That is my question - the reason for the flag being declined was inappropriate. How have you answered that question? You have not.*" There isn't an SE metric of appropriateness for decline reasons. A flag reviewer may choose any reason to decline a flag that may or may not reflect the real reason that they declined the flag. However, in this case, I agree with the flag reviewer, the answer you flagged **is** an answer in **my personal estimation**, like the estimation of whomever declined the flag. So we disagree with you. I don't think the answer should have been flagged at all

Comment: See my comment on @Richard 's answer here.

Comment: @Stinkfoot You and I have different ideas of what the "not an answer" flag is for. I think the people who declined your flag see it more my way than they see it it your way. There's no right or wrong here, just two (or more) different viewpoints on the purpose of the flag. Your flag was declined because the people who reviewed it disagreed that it should be flagged for that reason. That's all there is to say about it. If you want to try to understand *why* they disagreed, you might have to let go of what you think the flag means and try to see a different viewpoint.

Comment: I haven't the foggiest notion of what your talking about. The discussion with @Richard was about a different aspect entirely. _you might have to let go of what you think the flag means and try to see a different viewpoint_ - and you might want to stop preaching to me about how I should or should not think. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @Stinkfoot I wasn't talking about the discussion with Richard. We are just not understanding each other at all. Sorry if I offended. Just trying to explain reasons why your flag might have been declined. I wasn't trying to preach, just honestly trying to answer your question. Although now that I carefully re-read your question, I don't actually see a question there, more like a rant, I guess? So I shouldn't have tried in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it depends on which question you're talking about: the one in the title ("Why does one chord have different names?"), or the one implied in the original post itself ("Are these two chords the same?")? Since this is ultimately an educational setting, I think it's important to have posts that address both of these questions.

I was okay with this particular answer because it addressed the implied question. It was hidden in a lot of other information, and that information itself was confusing on account of some incorrect terminology, but the answer was there.

I'll quote from the original version of that answer:

> In Cdim7, dim7 means that the seventh is diminished (B♭♭). . . . In summary the chord is comprised by the notes C - E♭ - G♭ - B♭♭. . . . In Cm7♭5, the 7 means the chord contains a straight seventh

The author of this answer used "straight" in mean "minor," and as such they did actually answer the implied question.

Now, you're correct that that's still not the original question that the OP asked. But again, in an educational setting like this one, I think it's important to have answers that address both questions. Ideally both answers would be in a single answer, but that doesn't always happen.

Comment: Granted. Problem is the answer, FWIW, was **buried**, so IMO that doesn't qualify as an answer. @DavidBowling answered that part of the question quite clearly and simply, in the first sentence: **_Cdim7 and Cm7♭5 are not the same chord._** That is an **answer**. Information that answers a question after digging around for a while  is not answer, IMO. It's just the explanation for an answer that must be deduced. **Questions** need **Answers.** _Q: How much is 1+1? A: **2**_  |  _Q: Why do we have same chord but different name? A: **They are not the same chord.**_ Then explain why that is so.